# How can I start minecraft from a different folder via .bat file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Due me testing out various mods, I've created a cloned .minecraft folder called ".minecraft_modtesting" .

In my normal MC folder I've got a batch file with

> start /high javaw -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -Djava.library.path=bin/natives
>   -cp bin/minecraft.jar;bin/jinput.jar;bin/lwjgl.jar;bin/lwjgl_util.jar net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "name" "password"

However, I can't use this in ".minecraft_modtesting" because it starts the minecraft.jar from the ".minecraft" directory.

How can I change that please?

Comment: Just to clarify, you copied the `.bat` to your `.minecraft_modtesting` folder, ran it from there, and it didn't work? Because as far as I can tell, it should...

Comment: It did work, but it didn't start the minecraft.jar from .minecraft_modtesting but from .minecraft .

Comment: @Yves It won't work because Minecraft doesn't use the current folder for storage, it uses a particular location that's built-in to the game. It *can* be changed, but not by just starting it in a different folder.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah, I knew it used `%APPDATA%`, but I thought that since the batch file specifies the relative location `bin/minecraft.jar` as part of the classpath, it'd start from there; guess I was wrong, haha.